# UWP App, Add loading page while content loads

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I am building a UWP app which gets content from the internet, as I am pulling images it often takes some time to load. I would like to have a loading screen when a user navigates to one of these pages that has an image.

I have attempted to use a progress ring which is visible while the content is being loaded and collapses when content has loaded, however this has been unsuccessful.

What would be the best way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide any code that you tried and didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a placeholder (image with text "image is loading").
If you have a ListView or some other data control you can use attribute Phase for this purpose:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind myimages}">
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ImageInfo">
         <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
             <Grid>
          <Image Source="Assets/placeHolderImage.jpg" x:Phase="0" />
          <Image Source="{x:Bind Url}"  x:Phase="3" />
             </Grid>
         </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

As you can seein this template one image is placed over another. First is loading image with Phase="0" and when another one with Phase="3" is loaded it's placed over

Comment: can't we place a ProgressRing instead of the Image and give it Phase="0" without toggling its visibility?

Comment: @LayaleMatta, sure it could be possible to place any control instead image. One thing is that control should be smaller or same size as loading image